# Get Emails of Friends on Google Plus in Android

Tags: android, google-plus

I am creating an application in which I need to fetch the list of Emails of circle friends.

I tried following code but it is not working.

```
final String account = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

        AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
              URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me");
              String sAccessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(GooglePlusActivity.this, account,
                "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read");

              urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
              urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + sAccessToken);

          String content = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), Charsets.UTF_8));

              if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(content)) {
                JSONArray emailArray =  new JSONObject(content).getJSONArray("emails");

                for (int i = 0; i < emailArray.length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)emailArray.get(i);

                  // Find and return the primary email associated with the account
                  System.out.println(obj.getString("value"));
                  Log.d("jai ho", "jai ho"+obj.getString("value"));
                  if (obj.getString("type") == "account") {
                    return obj.getString("value");
                  }
                }
              }
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userAuthEx) {
              // Start the user recoverable action using the intent returned by
              // getIntent()
              startActivityForResult(userAuthEx.getIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN);
              return account;
           } catch (Exception e) {
              // Handle error
              // e.printStackTrace(); // Uncomment if needed during debugging.
            } finally {
              if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
              }
            }
```

please help me. If anyone is having good example so please post here.
And also please let me know if it is possible to get friends email or not.
I have don't googling for long time  but not getting exact information.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone also need to have the same application to have all the google emails of any G+ account but Google won't let you do that. Even for the user you are authenticating with, you can't have his email until you add the email scope to let the user accept granting his email to your app.